# Build and deploy in same build in teamcity and octopus

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I use teamcity for building and octopus for deploy.
We first run a build for building and test.
After that we use a new build to deploy to with help of octopus.
But I want that have it in same build but then it can not found nuget file.
Could not find package xxx 5.77 in feed: 'http://137.96.xxx.xxx:xxxx/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc/'

Answer (score 5):

As described in [Octopus documentation for integration with TeamCity](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/TeamCity), you must have two build configurations for this scenario. TeamCity does not publish NuGet packages in artifacts until a build is finished. Therefore Octopus cannot access them in that build.

You can learn more in [Deployment Automation with Octopus Deploy and TeamCity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWGLEEm9Qhg).

Answer (score 2):

We do the same thing.

Assuming you are using .Net, you need to include [OctoPack](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack) in the solution.

Then in Team City for the solution build step, you will see a new option for "Octopus Packaging". This basically creates a Octopus ready nuget package.

**Edit**
After reading Josef answer, I should add that in our workflow we have our own self hosted nuget server. So we don't rely on the nuget server builtin Team City

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same answers as you Jozef.
It is not possible to build and deploy in same if you want to use parameter "Wait for deployment to complete:" in deploy.
But the alternative is to pay 2000 euro, so we just removed the option "Wait for deployment to complete:" and hoping for the best....